# Retrieving Nested array in php using _POST

Tags: php, arrays

I have set the below in my HTML form. How do I retrieve it back in my PHP page(ON Submit)?

```
foreach ($rows as $i => $value) {
    echo "<br/>What do you think about : ";
    echo "<li>$value<br/>";
    echo "1<input type='radio' value='1' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "2<input type='radio' value='2' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "3<input type='radio' value='3' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "4<input type='radio' value='4' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "5<input type='radio' value='5' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";    
    }
?>
```

How do I retrieve my answer back ?

I use POST method for my form. Help me!!

Adding Details.

```
<?php
echo "hello";
$answer = _POST("answer");
echo $answer-0;
echo $answer[0];
foreach ($answer as $i => $value) {

    echo $value;
    echo $i;
}

?>
```

answer-0=3&answer-1=1

Above Values shows that The parameters are set(Get Method). But In POST METHOD I am not able to access them.

Can Someone help me? I still havent resolved the issue.

Comment: http://php.net/language.variables.external.php

Comment: <?php
echo "hello";
//echo $_POST("answer");
//echo $_POST('answer');
$answer = _POST("answer");
echo $answer-0;
echo $answer[0];
foreach ($answer as $i => $value) {

 echo $value;
 echo $i;
}

?>

Comment: here is what I have tried.. Nothing works.. It just prints hello

Comment: Everything else is commented out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post">
<?php

foreach ($_POST as $i => $value) {
    echo "$i&nbsp;$value<br/>";
}

echo $_POST['answer-1'];
echo "<br>";
echo $_POST['answer-2'];

$rows = array(
    "1" => "bar",
    "2" => "foo",
);

foreach ($rows as $i => $value) {
    echo "<br/>What do you think about : ";
    echo "<li>$value<br/>";
    echo "1<input type='radio' value='1' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "2<input type='radio' value='2' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "3<input type='radio' value='3' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "4<input type='radio' value='4' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";
    echo "5<input type='radio' value='5' name='answer-$i' />&nbsp;";    
    }
?>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Looks more like, what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use `$_POST` array with square brackets (it's an array).  This code will build an array of `$answers` for you, assuming you still have `$rows` available.

```
$answers = array();
foreach ($rows as $i => $value) {
    $answers[$i] = $_POST["answer-$i"];
}
print_r($answers);
```

Comment: If I try printing it it just says Array(). How Do i make it print values?

Comment: It will only be an empty array if you have no `$rows` - you need to have `$rows` just like when you built the form for this to work.

Comment: http://localhost/testingconn/WebContent/SecondForm.php?answer-0=3&answer-1=1 

Here is the value that gets popped when I use get method..

And Its in the post method that It doesnt work.

Comment: And how does my NewFile.php knows what rows is?? Because from my form action I open this NewFile.php